# moving box (C language)

Tags: c

1 = box
0 = nothing

0 1 0 1 0 0 → 1 1 0 0 0 0
and answer is 1+2 = 3

i don't know what is matter. Please tell me what is problem. Thank you so much!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX 99999
int main()
{
    int n;
    int i,j;
    int num=0;
    int distance;
    int total_distance;
    int box[MAX];
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&box[i]);
    }


    for(j=0;j<n;j++)
    {
        if (box[j]==1)
        {
            num++;
            distance = (j+1)-num;
            total_distance = total_distance + distance;
        }
    }
    printf("%d",distance);
}
```

Comment: How 010100->110000?

Comment: You also use `total_distance` without initialization.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @ZahidKhan He is trying to find the distance that 1's needs to be moved to achieve second sample from first one.

Comment: What exactly is the code supposed to do? It seems like a roundabout way of doing something that can probably be done in a much simpler way.

Answer (score 0):

You are printing:

```
printf("%d",distance);
```

instead I think you mean:

```
printf("%d",total_distance);
```

before this you should also initialize `total_distance` to 0.

Comment: That will print garbage! As total distance isnt initialised

Comment: @ZahidKhan It is clear that it needed to be initialized, as said in the comments, anyway I mentioned it also

Comment: @jinjin Please provide feedback whether this helps